# How to set the limit for multiline textbox in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, regex

I am Using `MultiLine Textbox` now I want to allow all the characters in it and I also want to set the limit of the textbox to 150 characters. So I want to use the regular expression so any one can help me.
I am using this regular expression:

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9\s!@#$%^&*()_+=-`~\\\]\[{}|';:/.,?><]*{1,150}$"
```

All working fine but it does not limit the characters to 150

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextBox.MaxLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) if TextMode property not set to MultiLine. [MaxLength property does not work for multiline textbox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/55695a7b-15ce-4371-b05d-6c09e1ca0bc8/maxlength-property-does-not-work-for-multiline-textbox-aspnet?forum=netfxjscript).

> Gets or sets the maximum number of characters allowed in the text box.
>   The value you set is the maximum number of characters allowed in the
>   text box. The default is 0, which indicates that the property is not
>   set.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Value1" Columns="2" MaxLength="3" Text="1" runat="server"/>
```

> If you want to let the user know if he exceeded the amount of
>   characters as he writes, you could use a javascript function attached
>   to keypress event. This function would test the length of the input
>   and cancel the character rendering if the maxlenght was reached.

**Check this**: [Set max length of MultiLine TextBox in ASP.Net](http://www.haidermrizvi.com/maxlength-multiline-textbox/#.VE9Y__mUdb4)

If you want to use the MultiLine mode then use java-script and RegEx way  to achieve the goal and follow the below reference links:
You can do it this way:

```
<asp:TextBox Rows="5" Columns="80" ID="txtCommentsForSearch" MaxLength="10" onkeyDown="return checkTextAreaMaxLength(this,event,'10');"  TextMode="multiLine" CssClass="textArea" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
```

//js

```
// JScript File

function checkTextAreaMaxLength(textBox, e, length) {

    var mLen = textBox["MaxLength"];
    if (null == mLen)
        mLen = length;

    var maxLength = parseInt(mLen);
    if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
        if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1) {
            if (window.event)//IE
            {
                e.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            }
            else//Firefox
                e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}

function checkSpecialKeys(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 35 && e.keyCode != 36 && e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 39 && e.keyCode != 40)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

**References:**
[ASP.NET - Limit number of characters in TextBox control](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/82655/ASP-NET-Limit-number-of-characters-in-TextBox-cont)
[Limit Number Of Characters In an ASP.NET Multiline TextBox using jQuery](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=396)
[TextBox: Minimum and Maximum Character Length Validation using ASP.Net RegularExpression Validators](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/TextBox-Minimum-and-Maximum-Character-Length-Validation-using-ASPNet-RegularExpression-Validators.aspx)
[Limit the number of characters of a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444943/limit-the-number-of-characters-of-a-textbox)
[Specifying maxlength for multiline textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334286/specifying-maxlength-for-multiline-textbox)
[How to set maxlength for multiline TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797726/how-to-set-maxlength-for-multiline-textbox)
[asp text box limit number of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111593/asp-text-box-limit-number-of-characters)

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to do this: Newer browsers support the `maxlength` attribute on `textarea` elements (but not IE9 and older versions of Internet Explorer).

You can limit `textarea` with javascript, or at least get the character count if you want to show "x chars remaining" (like posting a comment in SO).

For older browsers this javascript will check the length against the maxlength and prevent user from typing. However, since users can potentially defeat the `keydown` approach via copy and paste, etc., it is also a good idea to use `keyup` to truncate any overflow. Also, if data is going into the server/database it is not a bad idea to truncate and sanitize the input received from client in case the client bypasses the form and uploads POST data directly in which case `maxlength` has no effect.

In ASP.NET the markup looks like: `<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" TextMode="Multiline" ClientIDMode="Static" maxlength="150"/>` but for `textarea` (TextMode="Multiline") the `maxlength` attribute may not be rendered (perhaps depending on your ASP.NET version). You can verify in the markup whether it was rendered. If not, you may need to manipulate the TextBox's `Attributes` in the codebehind like this: `txt.Attributes["maxlength"] = "150";` (assuming C#)

JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/aymjsfdp/

```js
// "maxlength" code for older browsers including IE9 and previous versions
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
txt.onkeyup = function () {
    var maxlength = parseInt(this.getAttribute("maxlength")) || 0;
    if (maxlength > 0 && this.value.length > maxlength) {
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxlength);
        alert('text was truncated to ' + maxlength + ' characters.');
    }
    document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = this.value.length.toString();
};
txt.onkeydown = function () {
    var maxlength = parseInt(this.getAttribute("maxlength")) || 0;
    if (maxlength > 0 && this.value.length >= maxlength && (event.keyCode || event.which) > 49) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

```css
TEXTAREA {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>Chars: <span id='length'></span>
</div>
<textarea id='txt' maxlength='150'></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another Way
Below Code is available on the link:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Limit-number-of-characters-in-an-ASPNet-Multiline-TextBox-using-jQuery.aspx With the Demo Sample

```
<title>title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="MaxLength.min.js">script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        //Normal Configuration

        $("[id*=TextBox1]").MaxLength({ MaxLength: 10 });



        //Specifying the Character Count control explicitly

        $("[id*=TextBox2]").MaxLength(

        {

            MaxLength: 15,

            CharacterCountControl: $('#counter')

        });



        //Disable Character Count

        $("[id*=TextBox3]").MaxLength(

        {

            MaxLength: 20,

            DisplayCharacterCount: false

        });

    });

script>
```

head>

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="counter">

div>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300" Height="100"

    Text="Mudassar Khan">asp:TextBox>

<br />

<br />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300" Height="100">asp:TextBox>

<br />

<br />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300" Height="100">asp:TextBox>

form>
```

body>

html>